# What's wrong in this string comparison inside main method?

Tags: java

I am comparing a value of a string inside a main method, however, it keeps on saying that it is invalid.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "X";

    if(!a.equalsIgnoreCase("X") || !a.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: `!a.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")` is always true.

Comment: What letter should satisfy your test? What is valid, and what is invalid?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "X";

    if(!a.equalsIgnoreCase("X") || !a.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `a.equalsIgnoreCase("X")` is true, and `!a.equalsIgnoreCase("X")` is false.
- Since first condition is false, it evaluates the second condition.
- `a.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")` is false, and `!a.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")` is true.
- Second condition is true, hence "invalid" is printed.

**Note:** Maybe you should let us know what you are trying to achieve with the String comparisons, so that we can give you better feedback. Let us know what is the desired logic, i.e. what is valid, and what is not.

Based on the comment "Any letter that is not equal to "X" or "Z" should be invalid",
**Answer:**

```
if( !(a.equalsIgnoreCase("X") || a.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")) ) {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

or its equivalent (as proposed by Fast Snail):

```
if( !a.equalsIgnoreCase("X") && !a.equalsIgnoreCase("Z") ) {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

- ¬(X ∨ Z) ≡ ¬X ∧ ¬Z (De Morgan's Law)

Comment: Thanks men.. Any letter that is not equal to "X" or "Z" should be invalid.